# users creation ssrs

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

We are migrating SSRS from a work group server to a domain server. Is there a way to migrate all users from the existing server to the domain server? We have 300 windows users on the existing server. SQL 2008 R2 version.

Answer (score 0):

I think Active Directory Migration Tool should help you with the task. [Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc974332(v=ws.10).aspx) are details on where to get tool from. Microsoft also provides a [documentation/manual](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19188). There is also a discussion on a similar topic on [SQL Server Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d6f0e519-e650-4821-867b-62dc7bd8f3d9/modifications-requred-when-migrating-existing-ssrs-users-to-a-new-domain?forum=sqlreportingservices) if you need further guidance.